# Why does the DOM remove my classes automatically when the page is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a custom written accordion for my "sidenav", it's very simple, Just adding class on click event to trigger and menu items collapse but the problem is when I click on a link in the collapsed `<li>` the page starts to **redirect**; all the classes which I added with javascript click handler are **automatically removed** and it looks very ugly:

[image: Thats a gif]

... and how can I fix it? 
It's my javascript(jquery) and html code:

```
$('.mine-trigger').click(function(){

        var 
        control_click       = $(this).hasClass('mine-trigger-open'),
        howmuchchildrens    = $(this).children('.mine-content').children('.mine-content__link').length,
        calcPixels          = (howmuchchildrens * 48) + 'px';

        if (control_click == false){
            $(this).addClass('mine-trigger-open');
            $(this).children('.mine-content').css('max-height', calcPixels);
        }
        if (control_click == true) {
            $(this).removeClass('mine-trigger-open');
            $(this).children('.mine-content').css('max-height', 0);
        }
    });
```

```html
        <li class="mine-trigger">
            <a class="sidenav__link">
                <span class="sidenav__icon ico-person"></span>
                Cariler
            </a>
            <div class="mine-content">
                <a class="sidenav__link mine-content__link" href='<?php echo site_url('yonetim/cari')?>'>
                    <span class="sidenav__icon ico-person"></span>
                    Cari
                </a>    
                <a class="sidenav__link mine-content__link" href='<?php echo site_url('yonetim/personel')?>'>
                    <span class="sidenav__icon ico-assignment_ind"></span>
                    Personel
                </a>    
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: and sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Looks like you want to catch the click events on the menu items and prevent them from propagating up to your accordion elements

Comment: What's your HTML?

Comment: @D_N I addded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event is triggered from the LI so "this" will always be .mine-trigger and clicking on any child elements will toggle the close.  inspect the event.target to determine if the click was within a navigation link to determine if you should close the accordion.

```
$('.mine-trigger').click(function(e){
    var is_open = $(this).hasClass('mine-trigger-open');
    var from_link = is_open && $(e.target).closest('.mine-content__link').length == 1;

    if (!is_open) {
        // open accordion    
    } else if (is_open && !from_link) {
        // close accordion
    }
```

You could also get/set a cookie value or localStorage to re-open the accordion on the page you are navigating to.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the page **doesn't** *automatically* remove the classes you've applied.

Clearly, you deliberately apply them when a closed element is clicked, before removing them and setting the max-height of the children to 0.

You're setting the max-height attribute for the children, yet they appear slowly. That appears to indicate there's a transition being used when the "mine-trigger-open" class is applied. The max-height is set instantly, but the actual height changes over a period of time.

When you go the other way though, you instantly set the max-height attribute to 0. Even if there's a transition happening on the height attribute, you wont see the elements, since they've been hidden. Instead of applying the `max-height` attribute at this point, I'd suggest that it appear in the rule that governs the transition when "mine-trigger-open" is added or removed.